# Any docs on the permissions of the special InstallHandler package user?

Tags: managed-package, security

InstallHandler is the interface you implement for a post-install script in a managed package. Per [the docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_install_handler.htm):

> It runs as a special system user that represents your package, so all operations performed by the script appear to be done by your package. You can access this user by using UserInfo.

I just added some functionality to a previously working install script to populate a new custom field the package installs against Lead, but unexpectedly got

```
System.QueryException: sObject type 'Lead' is not supported.
```

when it ran as part of the InstallHandler. When the same code is executed in the target org by a normal user it runs fine.

I'm theorizing that this "special system user" has a limited set of permissions, and although I've worked around it for now I'd like to know what other limitation it has so I can avoid them. I can't find any docs on this though. Anyone know more than what's on the docs page above?

Comment: Does your package have any API restrictions by chance?

Comment: Nope, it's unrestricted, but it appears that perhaps the install handler runs before those preferences are applied?

Comment: I can't see any more public documentation than that, but I'll see if I can find someone that can provide more detail.

Comment: Can you post your code? I've been fighting intensely with some InstallHandler bugs over the past month and might be able to shed some light. Is all of your code within the class that implements InstallHandler (as opposed to some of it being extracted out into other classes)? Is it a "with sharing" class?

Comment: One "limitation"/ambiguity that I have confirmed with Tier 3 Support is that Describe methods, e.g. isAccessible(), on both fields and objects, always return FALSE (regardless of permissions). I have seen evidence that this also introduces ambiguities into the behavior of Dynamic SObject methods, e.g. SObject.get() and SObject.put() , so I would avoid using those at present. Tier 3 says that the Schema Describe ambiguities may be resolved by Spring 13 :(

Comment: @zachelrath I noticed your (excellent!) blog post, and pasted a link and excerpt as an answer. Hope that's ok with you!

Comment: @zachelrath sorry - I missed your follow-up comments. It looks like you've resolved them now, and shed a LOT of light on some of the issues I saw. Great article, thanks!!

Comment: @metadaddy yep that's cool with me. As long as folks get the info they need to avoid this hassle, i don't care who posts it :)

Comment: In case anyone finds this in the future, I just found another issue: the "with sharing" keyword on an InstallHandler also causes it to fail (or at least caused my install handler to fail - it was querying some core tables like Lead and Account). Not sure if that's documented anywhere but caused us a bit of head scratching before figuring it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No docs, but [zachelrath](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/398/zachelrath) has written an awesome blog post on the subject of install scripts: [Migrate your post-install and uninstall tasks to Apex Install Scripts](http://zachelrath.wordpress.com/2012/09/06/migrate-your-post-install-and-uninstall-tasks-to-apex-install-scripts/). I'm pasting the relevant info below, but go read the whole post!

> In the absence of documentation, the only way to find out was to
>   either ask questions of the SFDC community, or find out through
>   experimentation. I did both, and here are some things I discovered:
>
> - Install Scripts execute as a totally unique User and Profile
>
>   - Neither the User nor Profile exist in either Source or Destination orgs.
>   - This User / Profile has essentially ‘God’ / System privileges
>   - This User / Profile can create / modify records of Standard objects as well as Custom Objects / Custom Settings that come with the package being installed.
> - DML operations fail *if they are not initiated from the class which implements the InstallHandler interface*
>
>   - A DML operation executed from a helper class will fail due to SObjectExceptions such as “Field Name is not accessible”
>   - **Simply extracting this code back in to the class which implements InstallHandler can avoid this issue**
> - Schema Describe Information on Object or Field Accessibility always returns FALSE
>
>   - Calls such as Contact.Name.getDescribe().isAccessible() will universally return FALSE regardless of Profile permissions in either Source or Destination org
>   - Consequences: Do NOT try to dynamically determine whether to permit DML based on permissions from within Install Scripts. You will get very frustrated.
>   - **Timeline for Resolution**: Spring 13 release (Safe Harbor — got this from SFDC support)